# Will "Oilrush" be available for purchase from the Software Center?

Tags: software-center, games

[Oilrush](http://oilrush-game.com/) is a game with a high-end graphics engine due for release on the linux platform very soon. As a matter of fact, preordering is [already possible](https://store.unigine.com/products/category/oilrush/)!

That is why I would like to ask **whether it will be available for purchase in the Ubuntu Software Centre**.
If it will be offered, I would wait until it is available and buy it to support Ubuntu. If not, I'd rather buy it now and save some money.

Comment: is it going to cost more when it's in the Software Centre?

Comment: I expect it to because you currently get a preorder discount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitive answer: Maybe.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just to keep this up to date:

It is in the software center now! (In 11.04 Natty at least)

Answer (score -1):

I think it will, eventually, there is a post in [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/27219/) to add a few more paid apps to the Software Center. Besides, Oilrush is a huge release as a Linux game, there are few games that can be compared to it, and a lot of people are looking forward for a stable Ubuntu release.

#### EDIT:

I think i got your definitive no, i'm afraid. The Feature Freeze of the Natty development cycle was on February 24th. This means that no new packages will be added to the official repositories. AFAIK, unless they make an exception, we will have to wait until Ubuntu 11.10 to be able to purchase Oilrush from the software center.

More info [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze)

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, but I was more looking for a definitive yes or no :).

Comment: @IngoGerth Unless you get the actual software developers in here this is about the best answer you'll get. Publishers and Developers have to apply to have their app put in there. No one from community can do it - and no one really from Canonical can do it without their permission and legwork.

Comment: I'll try to get hold of them :)

Comment: I think things in the commercial part of the store don't apply as far as freezes and stuff.

Comment: @jorge-castro: It is possible, I don't know exactly